# Retrieve data from two tables with indirect relation(from another table)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables

```
Division 

id    name  
1       A 
2       B


Region

Id       name     Divsion_id
01      Rim          A


Territory

Id       name       region_id

001      a               01
002      b               01
003      c               01
```

Now I want to write a query such way that user will select division and its respective territories should get displayed.

How can I write this query, as

> there is no direct relation between Divsion and Region?

Comment: Are you sure devision_id is A in region table and not 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t.* from territory t
inner join region r on r.id = t.region_id
inner join devision d on d.name = r.division_id
where d.name = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `IN` operator with sub query. Inner query projects all regions having given region id and outer query looks for territories with selected regions. Though joins should perform better than nested query.

```
  select * from territory where region_id   in  (select region_id from region where devision_id=<division id>)
```

Comment: Please add context around the code so other users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.  I know it's obvious to you, but to other people, the point you're addressing isn't obvious.